# android sound pool not appear

Tags: android, media-player

I want to add a sound effect when a user clicks on a button.
I tried this:

```
case R.id.b_all_addresses_addAddress:
    // Getting the user sound settings
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
            .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
            .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
    if (loaded)
        soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 1, 1f);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "could I hate you God more?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

in my on create I did this:

```
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                    int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });
        soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.thip, 1);
```

the sound is just 6 KB.

#### My Problem

I can't hear the voice

Answer (score 0):

what values are you getting back for volume?

They should be between 0.1 and 0.99. Try using 0.5 as a hard-coded setting and see whether that works. I vaguely remember someone here once reported a "bug" in SoundPool which meant that 0 and 1 meant "mute" and your volume had to be between these two values in order to be heard.

Also: What format is your sound in? not all phones can play all the formats. Some need ogg, some are fine with WAV.

This here works for me on HTC Sensation XE, Android 4.03:
*WAV
*2 Channels 
*16 bit PCM
*44.1kHz